# Need for Speed Most Wanted 2005 is lagging in my laptop

Tags: graphics-card, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I have an Asus laptop with 2GB ram, a 500GB hard disk, Intel HD Graphics card in-build & DirectX12. I had installed Need for Speed Most Wanted 2005, but it works very slow and I can't complete a single race. I am using Windows 10 What should I do to fix this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: DirectX 12 is fine, but on what graphics hardware?

Comment: I am using inbuild Intel HD graphics

Comment: What are the graphic settings? If you can, turn them down.  Considering you only have 2Gb of RAM, it  sounds like you have a pretty old computer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/need-for-speed-most-wanted), the minimum specs for the game are as follows:

CPU: 1.4GHz or faster

RAM: 256MB or more

Graphics: Radeon 7500 or greater; ATI Radeon Xpress 200; NVIDIA GeForce2 MX/GTS or greater; Intel 950/i915g; S3 GammaChrome S18 Pro

Although it's an old game, I don't know that built in Intel Graphics are going to handle it.

Comment: How to know the problem and I am using Windows 10

Comment: Windows 10 might be another issue, the game was never rated for anything other than 2000 or XP.

Comment: But in my PC I am using Windows 8 but still game runs perfect

Comment: The newer integrated intel graphics should compete with those low end cards.  It depends on how old the processor is I'd say.

Comment: Uhhh so are you using Windows 10 or Window 8?

Comment: I am using windows 10